# Distribute objects with different sizes on face without overlapping - Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to distribute some objects on a face, I'm using the "Distribute Points on Faces" node with "Poisson Disk" which allows me to change the distance minimum to avoid overlapping.
But the problem is that the objects have different sizes, and setting the minimum distance according to the biggest object is not the perfect solution for me.
Is there any way to make the "distance min" change according to each object size?

[image]

Comment: Short answer: currently, unfortunately, no. `Distribute Points on Faces` does not know which objects you instantiate afterwards, and therefore cannot take into account the size of these objects.

Comment: @quellenform thank you for answering.